# how to remove the curly braces and user_cart string

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
public function addToCart($id){

$course = Course::findOrfail($id); 

$user =Auth::user();

$cart_array = array();

$cart = $user->user_cart;
if ($cart == '') {
  array_push($cart_array, array('user_cart' => $course->id));
  // print_r($cart_array);
    } else {
        $founder = false;
        $cart_array = json_decode($cart, true);
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($cart_array); $i++) {
            $cart_for_eacch_course = $cart_array[$i];
            if ($cart_for_eacch_course['user_cart'] == $course->id) {
                $founder = true;
            }
        }
      if (!$founder) {
    array_push($cart_array, array('user_cart' => $course->id));
  }
    }


$data['user_cart'] = json_encode($cart_array);

$update = User::where('id',$user->id)->update(['user_cart'=> $cart_array]);
```

**Current Output**

```
[{"user_cart":86},{"user_cart":84}]
```

**Expected Output**

```
[84,86]
```

Now I am having the current Output but I want expected one. I tried by removing the json_encode but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_column()` like so

```
$new_array = array_column($cart_array, 'user_cart');
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating the output array, you are using...

```
array_push($cart_array, array('user_cart' => $course->id));
```

which is why you get the sub arrays with the keys.  If instead you just add the `$course->id` values, then this should build the output in the first place rather than having to process it further...

```
$cart_array[] = $course->id;
```

You would also need to change the line

```
if ($cart_for_eacch_course['user_cart'] == $course->id) {
```

to

```
if ($cart_for_eacch_course == $course->id) {
```

as you no longer have the sub index.  You could change this part of the code to use `in_array()` instead which would also be shorter.

Comment: when i add one course to cart it get added but when the next course is added it shows the error which is as follows:

Trying to access array offset on value of type int

Comment: I've updated the answer, you may be better off re-writing the inner part of the code to use `in_array()` as I mention as you now have just a list on integers.

Comment: hey what if the situation is like this
      array_push($watch_history_array, array('lession_id' => $lesson_id, 'progress' => $progress));
How to write it so it will store only in one array not in arrray inside array